# Does pressing the Force touch trackpad hard damage it?

Tags: high-sierra, trackpad

So I just have this question because one time when I was cleaning my MacBook with a damp wet cloth, I started cleaning my trackpad but I didn't notice that I was clicking it very hard so I immediately took of the cloth and I stared testing whether my trackpad was working correcting by clicking random stuff it felt weird however after some 3 secs it worked perfectly fine like brand new. Should I worry about hardware damage to my force touch trackpad.

PS. I had also run a hardware test on my Mac and it reported 
"No Issues found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force trackpad is a piece of glass that doesn't move, but provides feedback based on where your fingers are using motors. Cleaning it with the damp cloth probably confused it as to where your fingers were, providing strange feedback until it dried a little.

But yes, really pushing your trackpad really hard could hurt it just like pushing on a piece of glass really hard can break it, but that seems unlikely given the strength of the glass.

As a fun experiment, shutdown your mac while clicking on the trackpad. You can tell when it shuts down completely because the trackpad stops clicking.